# Проблема: обученная нейронная сеть на Python для распознавания цифр не распознаёт мои цифры, но тестовые распознаёт с 97%-ной точностью

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Такая проблема: создал нейронную сеть на Python для распознавания рукописных цифр (28х28 пикселей) по книге Тарика Рашида "Создаём нейронную сеть":

```py
    class NeuralNetwork:
    '''Класс нейронной сети'''

    def __init__(self, input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes, learning_rate):
        '''Инициализация нейронной сети'''

        #Количество узлов ходного, скрытого и выходного слоёв
        self.inodes = input_nodes
        self.hnodes = hidden_nodes
        self.onodes = output_nodes

        #Коэффициент обучения
        self.lr = learning_rate

        #Веса между входным и скрытым и скрытым и выходным слоями
        self.wih = (np.random.rand(self.hnodes, self.inodes) - 0.5)
        self.who = (np.random.rand(self.onodes, self.hnodes) - 0.5)

        #Функция активации
        self.activation_function = lambda x: spc.expit(x)


    def train(self, inputs_list, target_list):
        'Тренировка нейронной сети'

        #Преобразование списка входных и целевых значений в двумерные массивы
        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = np.array(target_list, ndmin=2).T

        #Расчёт входных и выходный сигналов скрытого слоя
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        #Расчёт входных и выходных сигналов последнего слоя
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        #Ошибка выходного, и скрытого слоёв слоя
        output_errors = (targets - final_outputs)
        hidden_errors = np.dot(self.who.T, output_errors)

        #К-орректировка весов связей между выходным и скрытым слоями
        self.who += self.lr * np.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1-final_outputs)),
                                     np.transpose(hidden_outputs))

        #Корректировка весов связей между входным и скрытым слоем
        self.wih += self.lr * np.dot((hidden_errors * hidden_outputs * (1-hidden_outputs)),
                               np.transpose(inputs))


    def query(self, inputs_list):
        '''Опрос нейронной сети'''

        inputs = np.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T

        #Расчёт входных и выходный сигналов скрытого слоя
        hidden_inputs = np.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        hidden_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_inputs)

        #Расчёт входных и выходных сигналов выходного слоя
        final_inputs = np.dot(self.who, hidden_outputs)
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)

        return final_outputs
```

Сеть обучалась на 60000 тренировочных изображений MNIST в формате .csv:

```py
    #Количество входных, скрытых и выходных узлов
    inodes = 784
    hnodes = 200
    onodes = 10

    #Коэффициент обучения
    lr = 0.1

    n = NeuralNetwork(inodes, hnodes, onodes, lr)

    #Получение тренировочных данных
    training_data_file = open('mnist_dataset/mnist_train.csv', 'r')
    training_data_list = training_data_file.readlines()
    training_data_file.close()


    epoch = 5

    for e in range(epoch):
        for record in training_data_list:

            #Подготовка входных данных
            all_values = record.split(',')
            inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255 * 0.99) + 0.01

            #Подготовка выходных данных
            targets = np.zeros(onodes) + 0.01
            targets[int(all_values[0])] = 0.99

            #Тренировка сети
            n.train(inputs, targets)
```

После тестирования на 10000 тестовых изображений MNIST сеть показывает точность распознавания 97%, а при тестировании на 10 изображениях MNIST распознаёт все.

```py
    #Подготовка тестовых данных
    test_data_file = open('mnist_dataset/mnist_test.csv', 'r')
    test_data_list = test_data_file.readlines()
    test_data_file.close()

    scorecard = []

    for record in test_data_list:

        #Преобразование строки в список чисел и получение корректного значения
        all_values = record.split(',')
        correct_label = int(all_values[0])

        #Передача входных данных нейросети и получение выходных её данных
        inputs = (np.asfarray(all_values[1:]) / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01
        outputs = n.query(inputs)

        #Получение ответа сети из её выходного массива
        label = np.argmax(outputs)

        print(correct_label, '- истинное значение;', label, '- ответ сети')

        if (label == correct_label):
            scorecard.append(1)
        else:
            scorecard.append(0)


    scorecard_array = np.asarray(scorecard)
    print ("Эффективность -", scorecard_array.sum() / scorecard_array.size)
```

Вот результат после тестирования на 10000 изображений MNIST:

---

Эффективность - 0.9713

---

Но как только я тестирую сеть на своих изображениях, нарисованных в Paint, то точность распознавания еле дотягивает до 70%, но чаще 50 или 40% (я нарисовал 10 цифр от 0 до 9):

```py
our_own_dataset = []

for image_file_name in glob.glob('own_test_data/?.png'):
    #Получение метки изображения
    label = int(image_file_name[-5])

    #Получение массива из изобржения
    img_array = imageio.imread(image_file_name, as_gray=True)

    img_data = 255.0 - img_array.reshape(784)

    #Приведение значений массива к диапазону 0.01 - 1
    img_data = (img_data / 255.0 * 0.99) + 0.01

    #Добавление записи в массив
    record = np.append(label, img_data)
    our_own_dataset.append(record)

scorecard = []

for record in our_own_dataset:

    #Получение метки и массива пикселей изображения
    correct_label = record[0]
    inputs = record[1:]

    #Передача изображения нейронной сети и получение ответа
    outputs = n.query(inputs)
    label = np.argmax(outputs)

    print(correct_label, '- правильное значение;', label, '- ответ сети')

    if label == correct_label:
        scorecard.append(1)
    else:
        scorecard.append(0)

scorecard_array = np.asfarray(scorecard)
print('Эффективность -', scorecard_array.sum()/scorecard_array.size)
```

Вот результат:

---

0.0 - правильное значение; 0 - ответ сети
1.0 - правильное значение; 5 - ответ сети
2.0 - правильное значение; 2 - ответ сети
3.0 - правильное значение; 3 - ответ сети
4.0 - правильное значение; 4 - ответ сети
5.0 - правильное значение; 5 - ответ сети
6.0 - правильное значение; 6 - ответ сети
7.0 - правильное значение; 2 - ответ сети
8.0 - правильное значение; 8 - ответ сети
9.0 - правильное значение; 3 - ответ сети
Эффективность - 0.7

---

Вот некоторые из моих изображений:

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Подскажите, в чём может быть причина и как устранить проблему?
P.S. Примеры тренировочных изображений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Примеры тестовых изображений:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите пример тестового и тренировочного изображения.

Comment: абсолютно в этом не разбираюсь, но разве не логично что подобная сеть будет рассматривать изображения попиксельно, а не целостно? соответственно, где больше пикселей совпало ровно там, где они были расположены на обучающих изображениях - то и верно.

Comment: Хотя ваши тестовые изображения не видны, можно сказать следующее: ваша сеть распознает цифры на изображениях 28х28,а вы ей подаёте 140х140. В этом причина основная. Вторая в том на каких вы тренировали на монохромных или на полутоновых? Ваши изображения полутоновые.

Comment: @becouse тренировочное изображение https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBjzr.png  тестовое: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTKUm.png

Comment: Нарисованные вами изображения слишком большие

Comment: @becouse я подавал сети изображения 28х28 для теста, я их увеличил специально чтобы разместить здесь, извиняюсь, если ввёл в заблуждение) А тренировал сеть я только на полутоновых изображениях

Comment: Собственно mnist это учебный датасет. Идей две. 1 ваши цифры слишком тонкие. 2. Возьмите тестовые и добавьте к ним артефактов. Тогда будет понятно что происходит.

Comment: @becouse добавить к моим тестовым или к тестовым из mnist?

Comment: Да из mnist. На них же хорошие результаты.

Comment: @becouse я попробую

Comment: @becouse вряд ли дело в толщине цифр, автор книги тестировал сеть на своих цифрах, которые не менее тонкие, но сеть их успешно распознавала.Вот некоторые из них: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPnzJ.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/2roBq.png , https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFXq3.png

Answer (score 0):

На mnist вроде белое на черном фоне.
Сделайте графики обучения-зависимость эпох от ошибок,сделайте такой же график на keras,мне кажется ваша сеть неправильна,хотя по книги(такое естественно может быть):
Вот код keras с графиком,потом я сравнивал с графиком обучения своей сети(по виду):

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import History
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#map_nn=(28,12,13,14,7)

def plot_history(history):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    x=range(20)
    plt.plot(x,history.history['loss'])
    ax.set_xlabel("Epochs")
    ax.set_ylabel("Mse")
    plt.show()

np.random.seed(5)

# learn xor.Потом использую 
#x=np.array([[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0] ])
#y=np.array([[0],[1],[1],[0]])

# learn many
x=np.random.normal(size=(170,28))
y=np.random.normal(size=(170,7))


def get_data_x():
  return x

def get_data_y():
  return y

#map_nn=(28,12,13,14,7) аналогия с мое map nn

model=Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12,input_dim=28,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(13,activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(14, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='SGD',loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])
history=model.fit(get_data_x(),get_data_y(),epochs=20)
plot_history(history)
```

[image: обучение keras]
График моей сети был хуже->ошибки в коде.

Comment: Сделайте графики обучения-зависимость эпох от ошибок,сделайте такой же график на keras,мне кажется ваша сеть неправильна,хотя по книги(такое естественно может быть)

Comment: А чего комментарием, а не в ответе? Плюс, можете более подробно расписать, чтобы походило на полноценный ответ?

Comment: @Константин я привёл пример тренировочного и тестового изображения mnist в вопросе.Сеть обучалась на чёрных цифрах на белом фоне

Comment: Попробуйте белыми цифрами на черном фоне.